# Why do we need to restart Intelij IDEA after adding new plugin?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Every time we add a new plugin to Intelij IDEA, it needs a restart.

Plugins or extensions is a thing that should be plugged and unplugged without affecting main application. E.g. Google Chrome does not require a restart after extension installation.

Java also has a class loader mechanism, so it can load and use new classes after application start. So what's the reason Intelij IDEA still needs a restart?

Comment: shouldn't you ask this on the Jetbrains forum ? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics

Comment: why does stackoverflow has intelij-idea tag then?

Comment: to tag the IDE when you have a setup problem, just from top of my mind right now, but not to ask why this tool is in this way or the other way created. For that I think the better option is to ask directly on their forum/support. (PS: why is there an Java tag anyway? why not chrome)

Comment: why java? - because IDEA is written in java and this issue could be related to java platform

Comment: oh, then makes sens. Thanks for clearning that out.

Comment: What "issue"? It's definitely easier to do a restart to make sure that any old crud is out of the VM. Maybe they decided to take the easy road.

Comment: My guess: It needs a restart because the plugin you've added could be intended to affect how your IDE works when it initializes itself. Then adding such plugin at arbitrary time will mean that this plugin will not work correctly. IDE has no way to know that, so they chose a blanket approach that would work for sure rather than approach that may or may not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by @M. Prokhorov is basically correct. Many plugins perform customizations or register components that need to be executed during IDE startup. It is technically possible to analyze specific plugins and to detect whether they can be installed without restarting the IDE, but this work has simply never been a priority.

(JetBrains MPS, which is also based on the IntelliJ Platform, does support loading and unloading plugins without IDE restart, but for MPS it's a much more essential part of the workflow, and they didn't have any constraints in terms of compatibility with existing IntelliJ IDEA plugins.)

Comment: hi. thanks for the reply. can you give an example of a plugin feature that should be run only on startup and can't be attached to a running IDE? is it mostly a platform restriction rather than a plugin fault?

Comment: For example, if a plugin replaces some of IDEA's internal components and other components have dependencies on the components being replaced, such a replacement will not work after IDE startup. If a plugin only registers extensions for well-defined extension points, it can almost always be loaded dynamically.